# Jasmine spyOn calls original function

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

I have function in my module that makes an AJAX call, and upon success it redirects the user. I wanted to test that function in Jasmine, but I cannot get the page not to reload.

Here's my function:

```
function my_func() {
    $.ajax({
        // parameters
        success: function(data) {
            // does something
            reloadPage(path);
        }
    });
}    
function reloadPage(path) {
    console.log('got here');
    window.location.href = path;
}
```

In my test I spy the reload page function with:

```
spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function(options) {
    options.success(data);
});
spyOn(my_module, 'reloadPage');
my_module.my_func();
```

And when I run my tests I get this:

```
LOG LOG: 'got here'
Firefox 42.0.0 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
```

Shouldn't *reloadPage* be replaced by a spy and NOT called? I've included all the relevant code parts, it's 'literally' just that, but if you need me to provide more info let me know!

Comment: Have you tried swapping the order of the setup of the spies?

Comment: Yes, still the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing a fake call to the window reload (`reloadPage` function).
Also you are missing the `this` reference from the success function.

Here is how I modified your code and it works now.
You can see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/25/)

```
var my_module = {
  my_func: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'abc',
      success: function(path) {
        // does something
        self.reloadPage(path);
      }
    });
  },
  reloadPage: function(path) {
    console.log('got here');
    window.location.href = path;
  }
}

describe('reload page test', function() {
  it('test reload', function() {
    spyOn(my_module, 'reloadPage').and.callFake(function(e) {
      console.log("This is a spy call for reload page");
    });
    spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function(e) {
      e.success('some window url path');
    });
    my_module.my_func();
    expect(my_module.reloadPage).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
});
```